# How to use Watson Discovery Services to search for some pattern of text?

Tags: watson-discovery

I need to use Watson Discovery Services to search patterns of text from unstructured documents. It gives me the whole document as JSON. How can I apply a filter to train/find certain patterns during indexing or querying?

Comment: Can you please clarify - is your question about the data returned from your search (you want only the relevant passage/snippet) or is it about how to structure a query to return what you want, given that entire documents return?

Comment: I found out that we need to use Watson Knowledge Studio to train and annotate. Then Use the model to refine the search in Discovery Service.